# Webpage Java Applet - Open On Screen Keyboard

Tags: java, applet, embed, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to open the On Screen Keyboard from within a web application on a touch screen interface. I am using Opera as the browser for the built in "Kiosk" features, but it does not support VBScript- an easy way of openning a .exe file from a webpage.

I know Java can be ran from within a web page and it can also be used to open another application, such as the OSK!

Below is my working Java code:

```
package runtimeexec;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RuntimeExec {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("cmd /c osk");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to embed this into a webpage, so that it can open the osk. My .class file is at http://theyconfuse.me/java/runtimeexec/RuntimeExec.class and my current attempt to embed this code is at http://theyconfuse.me/java/ with the following embed code:

```
<applet codebase="http://theyconfuse.me/java/runtimeexec" code="RuntimeExec.class" width="200" height="200"></applet>
```

How ever, when I load the page, I get the following:

> NoClassDefFoundError
>
> RuntimeExec (wrong name: runtimeexec/RuntimeExec)

Can anyone help me with what am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code="RuntimeExec.class"
```

Should be with `package` structure, separated by dots, but without the `.class` extension.

```
code="runtimeexec.RuntimeExec"
```